# Download all attachments received in the past 30 days

Tags: python, outlook

Below is my code.

```
import win32com.client,datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders('Paper & CD')
messages = inbox.Items
date_now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
date_before = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(-30)).date()
for msg in messages:        
    for att in msg.Attachments:
        if att.FileName == 'list.csv': 
            att.SaveAsFile('C:\\My\\temp\\' + msg.subject + att.FileName)
        att.SaveAsFile('C:\\My\\temp\\' + att.FileName)
```

It downloads all attachments from the particular folder.

I need to download only attachments not more than 30 days old.

I tried with `msg.LastModificationTime` but it gives last modified time of mail.

I want to know the received date for each mail so I can compare it with current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext` with a restriction based on the `ReceivedTime` property.